# Cordova cli adds res folder to /www with 7.5mb of default splash screens / icons

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I'm using Cordova 3.4. When I use `cordova build ios` to build my app, the CLI adds a folder called 'res' to my platform /www folder. It contains all the default splash screens and icons for all platforms, including iOS, Android, Tizen, Bada, Blackberry, etc etc. Uncompressed this folder is about 7.5mb. It adds this folder every time I run build.

I can manually remove the folder from the platform /www folder after building without problem (Splash screens and icons on iOS are defined in the Xcode project anyway) but doing this by hand every time I want to push a build to our testing distribution system or iTunes seems like a huge hassle.

Is there any way I can prevent Cordova from adding folder?

Comment: Is there a folder called 'res' under your cordova 'www' directory?

Comment: There is actually. Thanks for responding! See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Cordova 3.4 adds this folder by default when you do `cordova platform add <platform>`. It didn't in previous versions which is why I didn't caught it earlier. I could remove the folder from my /www folder without cordova build failing. All is well.